# Postgresql OVER

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have data like:

| id | user | index |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aaa | 0 |
| 2 | bbb | 0 |
| 3 | aaa | 1 |
| 4 | bbb | 1 |
| 5 | aaa | 2 |
| 6 | ccc | 0 |

How to get only the latest index of each user ?

Like this result

| id | user | index |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | bbb | 1 |
| 5 | aaa | 2 |
| 6 | ccc | 0 |

Comment: Please can you [edit] your question to include what research you've done so far - if you've tried some SQL and it didn't give the result you want, show that, along with the output or exact error message you got; if you've found other questions here or links online, include those and explain why they weren't enough for you to make progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a simple `DISTINCT ON`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON ("user")
       id, "user", "index"
FROM mytab
ORDER BY "user", "index" DESC;
```

This will return the first row per `"user"` in the specified ordering, so the maximum `"index"`.

It is a good idea to avoid column names that are reserved SQL keywords.

Comment: Looks like OP wants the result in id order.

Comment: To sore the result in `id` order, you can wrap the query from the answer with `SELECT * FROM (...) AS q ORDER BY id;`.

Answer (score 1):

In PostgreSQL you can use the following:

```
WITH CTE(id,userr,indexx) AS 
 (
    select 1 ,  'aaa' , 0 union all
    select 2,   'bbb' , 0 union all
    select 3 ,  'aaa' , 1 union all
    select 4 ,  'bbb' , 1 union all
    select 5 ,  'aaa' , 2 union all
    select 6 ,  'ccc' , 0  
 )
 select distinct on(c.userr) c.userr,c.indexx,c.id
   from cte as c
     order by c.userr,c.id desc,c.id;
```